# invalid use of template-name 'TableOfHash' without an argument list

Tags: c++

In the following line:

```
TableOfHash::TableOfHash<T>(): array(new NodeOfHash<T>[13]),
                            size(13), usedElems(0) {
}
```

I get the following error message:

> error: invalid use of template-name 'TableOfHash' without an argument list
>    TableOfHash::TableOfHash(): array(new NodeOfHash[13]),...

This is hash.h:

```
template<class T>
class NodeOfHash{
public:
    List<T> list;
};

template<class T>
class TableOfHash{
public:
    NodeOfHash<T>* array;
    int size;
    int usedElems;
    TableOfHash();
    void** add(int id, T* value, void** node);
    void rehashing(Node<T>* node );
    ~TableOfHash();
};
```

Can please someone assist?

Comment: Looks like you used `Node<T>`instead of `NodeOfHash<T>` in one place....

Comment: Have you tried `TableOfHash<T>::TableOfHash()`?

Comment: It just worked!! @melpomene is right. thanks